# move service applications from one farm to another farm in SharePoint 2010

Tags: service-application

Would like to move the below service applications from one farm to another:

1. Managed Metadata Web Service
2. Web Analytics Web Service

please suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the Managed Metadata SA: copy (backup/restore) the database and recreate the MMS SA in the new farm pointing to the restored DB.

For Web Analytics: why would you ever want to do that? The information is tied to the farm it comes from.

Comment: Web Analytics consumes high CPU usage on the DB server, so decided to move it to SAF...any suggestion?

Comment: Yes, Web Analytics is a resouce consuming beast. But you asked about moving it from one farm to another farm? Just recreate the WA SA on the new farm and start from scratch.

Comment: do not want to lose the existing WA stats, is there a way to bring those data into the new WA?

Comment: The data in the WA will be worthless unless you restore the whole farm.